# Php get particular value from xml node (calling node name)

Tags: php, xml

Xml

```
<CRates>
    <Currencies>
        <Currency>
            <ID>AED</ID>
            <Units>1</Units>
            <Rate>0.17200000</Rate>
        </Currency>
        <Currency>
            <ID>ATS</ID>
            <Units>1</Units>
            <Rate>0.04102750</Rate>
        </Currency>
    </Currencies>
</CRates>
```

Want to get for example `Rate` value where `ID` is ATS

At the moment can get only in such way

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml');
echo $xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency[1]->Rate;
```

`<ID>ATS</ID>` is within the second `<Currency>`, so `Currency[1]`

Of course `echo $xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency[ATS]->Rate;` does not work. But is any simple way to get it work?

Seems need to use `foreach` and inside foreach if `<ID>` == ATS, echo `<Rate>`

Comment: I think you can find this link helpful http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmliterator.getchildren.php

Comment: i am confused, what do you want to do? Pull all the Rate values? Only for a specific ID?

Comment: Only specific `<Rate>` of `<Currency>` where `<ID>` matches set condition. For example, user wants to see Rate for currency ATS. So need to show the Rate only for currency ATS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// This way should work for all versions of PHP
$rate = false;
foreach ($xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency as $currency)
{
    if ((string)$currency->ID == 'ATS')
    {
        $rate = (string)$currency->Rate;
        break;
    }
}

// This way should work for newer versions of PHP only, I personally think that anonymous functions like this add to the readability which is why I included both options
$rate = call_user_func(function() use ($xmlDoc) {
    foreach ($xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency as $currency)
    {
        if ((string)$currency->ID == 'ATS')
            return (string)$currency->Rate;
    }
    return false;
});

// Using false to signify failure is the standard in PHP
if ($rate !== false)
    echo 'The rate is: ',$rate;
else
    echo 'Rate not found';
```

You may not need to cast to string but I believe if you don't you'll end up with SimpleXMLElement objects (or something with a similar name) rather than strings.

Comment: +1 but I would use `if(!empty($rate))` instead of `if($rate != false)` in case the rate approaches 0 for any reason. also, you have an extra trailing = in that final if statement..

Comment: @XaxD - Returning false when something fails is the standard in PHP.  Most functions already act that way and many are being changed towards that model.  Not a typo "!==" rather than just "!=" will ensure it is false *AND* of the same type so "-1" won't be treated as a miss.

Comment: @XaxD - echo takes infinite parameters so comma is preferred to period as it will echo them both individually rather than concatenating first.

Comment: @XaxD - np, both things are actually common oversights.  I'd actually encourage you to leave the comments as it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using xpath, something like:

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml'); 
// find all currency records with code value of ATS
$result = $xmlDoc->xpath("Currencies/Currency/ID[.='ATS']/parent::*");  
print_r($result);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => ATS
            [Units] => 1
            [Rate] => 0.04102750
        )

)
```

while

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml'); 
print_r($xmlDoc); 
// find all currency records with code value of ATS
$rate = $xmlDoc->xpath("Currencies/Currency/ID[.='ATS']/parent::*"); 
print_r((float) $rate[0]->Rate);
```

gives

```
0.0410275
```

Comment: In output get `Array ( ) `

Comment: @user2465936 - I may be wrong but I believe print_r doesn't work properly with SimpleXML.  Unsure why but I've used it a bunch and my brain is having incomplete flashbacks.

Comment: Modified for case-sensitivity, and use of `ID` rather than `code`